# JQUERY: Storing div ID and checked value into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to store the div ID and the checked value into an array.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oa0nsvhf/)

Suppose I check ***samsung*** and ***lenovo*** from **brands** and ***4gb*** from Ram, the array should be:
array[  ] = ["brands" => "samsung,lenovo" , "ram" => "4gb"]

HTML

```
 <div id="brand">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Samsung">Samsung<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Nikon">Nikon<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Lenovo">Lenovo<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Alcatel">Alcatel<br>
 </div>
 
<div id="ram">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="2 GB">2 GB<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="3 GB">3 GB<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="5 GB">5 GB<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="6 GB">6 GB<br>
</div>
```

The divs are dynamically grabbed from the server. This is just an illustration, there are multiple divs and the ID's of them are not known. 
Any help is appreciated.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I think you can use Json to do it, specially if you want to sen this data to a server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I usually use $.post to send data to a server. So, a Jquery example  would be useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing an `Object` having properties same as element `id` , set property having same name as element `id` to selected `input` value

```js
var res = {
  "brand": "",
  "ram": ""
};
$("#brand, #ram").on("change", function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;
  // if `e.target.value` `val` begins with character `a-z` , case insensitive
  // set `brand` property of `res` with `val` , 
  // else set `ram` property with `val`
  res[/^[a-z]/i.test(val) ? "brand" : "ram"] = e.target.value;
  console.log(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="brand">
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Samsung">Samsung
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Nikon">Nikon
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Lenovo">Lenovo
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="Alcatel">Alcatel
  <br>
</div>

<div id="ram">
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="2 GB">2 GB
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="3 GB">3 GB
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="5 GB">5 GB
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" value="6 GB">6 GB
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. But i dont know the ID of Divs since they are  send from the server. What can i do in this case?

Comment: Thankyou again. This should work if i have two divs. But i have multiple divs       value  beginning with character as well as number.

Comment: @SushangNirola `html` at Question appear to have two `div` elements , two `id`'s for two elements . `"#brand"` `input` appear to have all a-z characters as `value` ; `#ram` `input` appear to begin with digit . `.test()` checks for value of `input` , not `id` of element .